# How to obtain the n-th derivative of $1/(-x+xe^{(i \pi x)})$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Wolfram Alpha symbolic integer derivative to this [question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5En%2Fdx%5En%201%2F(-x%2Bxe%5E(i%20pi%20x))) is wrong.

How can i obtain it by *Mathematica*?
Thanks

```
 D[1/(-x + x*Exp[I*Pi*x]), {x, n}]
```

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau,Maybe you open this question?

Comment: In V13, the OP's code `D[1/(-x + x*Exp[I*Pi*x]), {x, n}]` now works.

Answer (score 3):

From Maple:

> $\sum _{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (-m)_m x^{-1-m} \frac{\partial ^{m-n}}{\partial x^{m-n}}\frac{1}{\exp (i \pi  x)-1}$

Finding n-th derivative:

> $f(x)=\frac{1}{-1+e^{i \pi  x}}$

```
f[x_] := 1/(Exp[Pi*I*x] - 1)
func = SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, m}]
func = FullSimplify[func, {m \[Element] Integers, m > 0}]
```

[image]

$$f(x)=\sum _{m=-1}^{\infty } \text{SeriesCoefficient}[f(x),\{x,0,m\}] x^m$$
$$\frac{\partial ^nf(x)}{\partial x^n}=\sum _{m=-1}^{\infty } \text{SeriesCoefficient}[f(x),\{x,0,m\}] \frac{\partial
   ^nx^m}{\partial x^n}$$
$$\frac{\partial ^nf(x)}{\partial x^n}=\sum _{m=-1}^{\infty } \text{SeriesCoefficient}[f(x),\{x,0,m\}] \binom{m}{m-n} n! x^{m-n}$$

```
Sum[func*Binomial[m, m - n]*n!*x^(m - n), {m, -1, Infinity}]
```

MMA can't find sum :(. Changing index `m` to `m-1` in sum to be `m=0`:

> $$\frac{\partial ^n\frac{1}{(-1+e^{i \pi  x})}}{\partial x^n}=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((i \pi )^{m-1} B_m\right) \binom{m-1}{m-n-1} n! x^{m-n-1}}{\Gamma (1+m)}$$

Substituting to first sum.

> $$\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}(\frac{1}{-x+x \exp (i \pi  x)})=\sum _{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (-m)_m x^{-1-m} \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left((i \pi )^{j-1} B_j\right) \binom{j-1}{j-n+m-1} (n-m)! x^{j-n+m-1}}{\Gamma (1+j)}$$

Check numerics:

```
n = 2;
N[D[1/(-x + x*Exp[I*Pi*x]), {x, n}] /. x -> 1, 50]
(*-1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - 
1.5707963267948966192313216916397514420985846996876 I*)

N[Sum[Binomial[n, m]*Pochhammer[-m, m]*x^(-1 - m)*
Sum[((I \[Pi])^(j - 1) BernoulliB[j])/Gamma[1 + j]*
Binomial[j - 1, j - n + m - 1]*(n - m)!*x^(j - n + m - 1), {j, 
0, 1000}], {m, 0, n}] /. x -> 1, 50]
(*-1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 - 
1.5707963267948966192313216916397514420985846996876 I*)
```

It seems that the result is correct.

**Update 07.02.2017:**

Let's take a simple case:

```
  Sum[Exp[-k*x], {k, 1, Infinity}]
  (*1/(-1 + E^x)*)
```

N-th derivative of $e^{-kx}$ is $e^{-kx}(-k)^n$ then:

```
  Sum[Exp[-k*x]*(-k)^n, {k, 1, Infinity}]
  (*(-1)^n PolyLog[-n, E^-x]*)
```

> $$\frac{\partial ^n\frac{1}{(-1+e^{i \pi  x})}}{\partial x^n}=(-i \pi )^n \text{Li}_{-n}\left(e^{-i \pi  x}\right)$$

```
D[1/(Exp[Pi*I*x] - 1), {x, n}] == (-I \[Pi])^n PolyLog[-n, E^(-I \[Pi] x)]
```

> $$\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial x^n}(\frac{1}{-x+x \exp (i \pi  x)})=\sum _{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} (-m)_m x^{-1-m} (-i \pi )^{m-n} \text{Li}_{-m+n}\left(e^{-i \pi 
>    x}\right)$$

```
Sum[Binomial[n, m]*Pochhammer[-m, m]*x^(-1 - m)*(-I \[Pi])^(m - n)
PolyLog[-m + n, E^(-I \[Pi] x)], {m, 0, n}]
```

where: $\text{Li}_n(x)$ is polylogarithm function.

Comment: And how you know the n-th derivative of 1/(-1+e^(i pi x)) in mathematica since wolfram alpha dont answers that?

Comment: Maybe send your question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/ .There you will get the answer, if it is possible.

Comment: $Kevin67.I'm updated the answer. :)